# What slider was used in unity3d.com/5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I stumbled across the http://unity3d.com/5 website and I thought the slider effect (that closes towards the centre) in the "graphics" section was interesting. Just hoping to know how to achieve such effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PagePiling](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js)

It seems to have an option for directions, too, so I guess it could be done horizontally, as well. The effect is called a `curtain` effect.

Comment: it doesn't really have the "slider effect (that closes towards the centre)" but managed to find it here http://codyhouse.co/demo/3d-curtain-template/index.html